# command line friendly search engine, for use with Links

Tags: search, web, links

Are there any search engines that are friendly enough to be used in Links? Perhaps a google proxy that has no clutter, I find that Google takes a lot of navigating through the mass of links before being able to put cursor in the  search bar, bing a little less, duck duck go is almost there but search results work better in google in my opinion.

Is there a better search engine I can use or maybe something I can do in Links to get to the seach box faster, currently using arrow keys.

Comment: @manatwork thanks but google.com/m doesn't seem to work atall in Links, spools of some wml no search box.

Comment: Using numbered links ameliorates the pain a lot, run `links` with these arguments `-html-numbered-links 1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Surfraw website](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/):

> Surfraw provides a fast unix command line interface to a variety of popular WWW search engines and other artifacts of power. It reclaims google, altavista, babelfish, dejanews, freshmeat, research index, slashdot and many others from the false-prophet, pox-infested heathen lands of html-forms, placing these wonders where they belong, deep in unix heartland, as god loving extensions to the shell.

Essentially, Surfraw uses a series of discrete shell scripts (called Elvi) that allow you to interact directly with the search function of over 100 websites—including this one—and search engines like DDG and Google.

So, for example, to search this site, you would just enter:

```
sr stack -u -s=new browsers
```

to search for questions tagged 'browsers' and your request would be handed off to the CLI browser of your choice.

If you add Surfraw to your $PATH, you just have to enter:

```
stack -u -s=CATEGORY $TAG
```

The website has a full [list of Elvi](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/#elvilist).

Comment: This is perfect, never even knew it existed. Thanks.

Comment: `surfraw` has [moved to gitlab](https://gitlab.com/surfraw/Surfraw), where you may need to find it for documentation.  (The `man` page is not up to date.)